# Highlight model in Autodesc Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I use following function to highlight model in viewer:

```
function selectModel(model) {
    viewer.impl.selector.setSelection(model.getData().fragments.fragId2dbId, model);
}
```

Is it right? May be the better method exists? Documentation is very pure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a single model, you can simply do a `viewer.select` of the root node:

```
var instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree

var rootId = instanceTree.getRootId()

viewer.select(rootId)
```

With multiple you can use the following, which lets you specify on which model you want to enable the selection:

```
viewer.impl.selector.setSelection([rootId], viewer.model)
```